# Linked list using dynamic memory

Tags: c++, beginner, object-oriented, linked-list, reinventing-the-wheel

I created a simple linked list to test what I've learned so far and if I manage everything correctly. If you see syntax errors is't because of copy-paste. I just want to know if i'm making everything in the right way without 
having leak and memory problems.

**`Node` class**

```
#include "Node.h"


//Constructor.
Node::Node(int v)
:next(nullptr), value(v)
{
}


//Deconstrucor (not in use).
Node::~Node()
{
}


//Set next.
void Node::set_next(Node *new_node)
{
    this -> next = new_node;
}


//Set previous.
void Node::set_prev(Node *new_node)
{
    this -> prev = new_node;
}


//Set value.
void Node::set_value(int v)
{
    this -> value = v;
}


//Get next.
Node *Node::get_next()
{
    return this -> next;
}


//Get previous.
Node *Node::get_prev()
{
   return this -> prev;
}


//Get value
int Node::get_value()
{
    return this -> value;
}
```

**`LinkedList` class**

```
#include "LinkedList.h"
#include "Node.h"
#include <new>
#include <iostream>


//Constructor.
LinkedList::LinkedList()
:head(nullptr), tail(nullptr), moving_ptr(nullptr)
{
}


//Deconstrucor (not in use).
LinkedList::~LinkedList()
{
}


//Append a new item on the list.
void LinkedList::append(int v)
{

    //Allocate a new node.
    Node *new_node = new (std::nothrow)Node(v);


    //If memory is full, exit the program.
    if (new_node == nullptr){
        std::cout << "Memory is full, program will exit." << std::endl;
        exit(0);
    }


    //If this is the first node.
    if (head == nullptr || tail == nullptr)
        {
            head       = new_node;
            tail       = new_node;
            moving_ptr = new_node;
        }


    //Append other node.
    else
        {
            tail -> set_next(new_node); //Link it after the tail of the list.
            new_node -> set_prev(tail); //Set the previous node.
            tail = new_node;            //Update the tail pointer.
        }
}



//Remove a node from the list.
bool LinkedList::remove_item(int v)
{

    //Starting node.
    Node *curr = head;


    //----Find the node that contains v----//
    while (curr != nullptr)
    {

        //Found.
        if (curr -> get_value() == v)
            break;


        //Keep going.
        else
            curr = curr -> get_next();
    }
    //----Find the node that contains v----//



//The item was not found into the list.
if (curr == nullptr)
    return false;



//Make necessary links!!!
curr -> get_prev() -> set_next( curr -> get_next() );


//Delete current node.
delete curr;

return true;
}



//Get the next item.
int LinkedList::nextItem()
{

    //Temp that hold current value.
    int temp = moving_ptr -> get_value();


    //Move to the next node.
    moving_ptr = moving_ptr -> get_next();

    //Return the value.
    return temp;
}


//Return true if moving_ptr is not null.
bool LinkedList::hasNext()
{
    return moving_ptr != nullptr;
}


//Reset moving_ptr.
void LinkedList::reset()
{
    moving_ptr = head;
}
```

Am I handling everything correctly? I also tried to fill all my memory with an infinite loop to see what happens and everything run's smoothly. The program terminates when memory is full.

Comment: As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, try to write a title that summarizes what your code does, not what you want to get out of a review. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review - Asking Questions](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2438/31562) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Comment: Are you aware that C++ has a linked list container type? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/

Comment: yes i'm aware. Thats only for educational purposes.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: so i should post an anwer with the updated code?

Comment: @babaliaris Generally, people don't post answers with the updated code.  Unless you are providing additional critique of your code in the form of a review it can be viewed as off topic and deleted, although this generally doesn't happen if it's posted as community wiki.  Once you fix the memory leaks, you can post your updated code as another question and ask for further feedback if you think it would be useful.

Comment: @babaliaris You may also want to take a look at some of the [other linked list implementations](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linked-list%20c%2b%2b)

Comment: Without the types of the members this is impossible to review. In C++ the most important part is the type information. So without the class declarations this is impossible to review. Voting to close.

Comment: Agree with @LokiAstari, we need definition of the classes. Namely .h files. With it we can give you much more concrete review.

Answer (score 1):

**Memory Leaks**

You aren't cleaning up after your `LinkedList`.  When the class is destroyed you want to make sure that all of the memory it has allocated is cleaned up.  At a minimum, you're going to want to:

```
LinkedList::~LinkedList()
{
    delete head;
}
```

However you also need to consider each node in the list.  You can either have `~Node` delete it's `next`, or you can put a loop in to delete all the items in the list from the tail backwards.  Usually you would also implement this in a public function like `clear` or `flush` so that the whole list can be easily emptied.  For example, something like this would clear up the list:

```
void clearList() {
    Node *tmp = head;
    while(tmp) {
        head = tmp->get_next();
        delete tmp;
        tmp = head;
    }
}
```

**Exit**

You exit if there is insufficient memory to allocate a `node`.  The exitcode 0 is usually reserved for a successful program exit.  You should be passing a different value to exit (usually a negative number) to indicate failure.

**Heads or Tails**

In your `remove_item` method, you're not updating your tail pointer, what is going to happen if the tail happens to be pointing at the node that contains the value you remove?  Similarly, what happens if `moving_ptr` is pointing at the node that's removed?

**reset**

I'd honestly expect this to clear/flush/empty the list, not just reset the pointer that's used for iterating over items in the list.  This is likely to be confusing.

**templates**

Depending on what it is you're practising for, a good next step would be to adapt your `Node` so that it can support a templated value type.  You could then extend the list to store and retrieve values of any type.

Comment: fare enough :p Ok i know what do u mean by cleaning up all the nodes.
Also i will correct the exit state. Thanks :)

Comment: OMG you are right about the remove method, didn't notice that :p
Thank's :p

Comment: @babaliaris I've added an example of `clearList`, which could be called in the destructor for the list.  I haven't tested it, but it should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you a lot! I also updated my remove_item method to update the `tail` and the `moving_ptr`. I will also see about templates. I already know them from java :p but never seen them in c++

Comment: I am voting down. You comments are based on assumptions that you can not know without seeing the types of the members. Example: The need to delete will depend on the type of head. If it is a RAW pointer then yes, but what if it is a unique_ptr?

Comment: @LokiAstari Then I'm pretty sure this: `head       = new_node;` would cause the compiler to barf.

Comment: @forsvarir: Not if it was `std::auto_ptr`. The point is there are a million different things that could happen. You are just guessing. Without type information (the most important thing in C++) your ability to review the code is inhibited completely and your advice could be correct or completely wrong.

Comment: @LokiAstari I believe `auto_ptr` would have caused the compiler to barf on `Node *curr = head`, so I'm still comfortable believing that based on the supplied code it is using a raw pointer and that my advice is valid.  However I take your point.